# How to create a Parcelable Session data?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

is it possible to create a parcelable session and pass it from one activity to another. is it possible, then how should i do that ?

i am trying to develop a Facebook app using Facebook SDK in android.

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson, i am new in android and FB sdk. can you please tell me how can i access the current user's session data from any Activity via the Facebook Android SDKs's methods. thank you.

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson, by the way, i am using SessionLogin approach to login into facebook.

Comment: I wrote up an answer - let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to pass the session data between Activities. You can directly access the Session data from any Activity by saving the access token and expiry time to persistent memory and then access them either from SharedPreferences in your Activity or via your own Session class.

For a complete example of how to do login to Facebook and request data from different Activities have a look at the Hackbook example of github:

[Hackbook app source code on github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook)

and a walk-through on [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/#login).

In the HackBook, there is a class called `SessionStore` which stores the access token and access expiry time. Have a closer look at that as a start.

Edit:

Here is a step-by-step tutorial on how to create a basic Android Facebook app with auth and login:

[Android Facebook Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

When going through the Hackbook, start by reading the code to the class [`Hackbook`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/Hackbook.java). It covers the auth, login and some examples calls to get a friend list etc. If you understand this class you'll understand how the app works.

Comment: it was too tough for me to understand :( so, to avoid the complex things, i just declare my session as a global variable in one activity like `public static Session toSendSession` and retrieve the value from another activity like `Session session = oneActivity.toSendSession`.
it works for me. but i don't think that this is a good idea. but i will learn it from Hackbook as you suggest. thank u for your suggestion. but, can u give me any tutorial link for understanding the total workflow of Hackbook. thaknx @GunnerKarlsson

Comment: I've edit my answer with a link to a step-by-step tutorial. Thing is, the Facebook auth and login on Android isn't easy to totally understand, so take your time, test it in small steps.

Comment: i have followed the "Scrumptious Tutorial" tutorial, and now i am able to handle my situation , thank u for your help it helps me to find out the tutorial @GunnerKarlsson